# Как создать MockMultipartFile в нужной директории?

Tags: java

Для тестирования контроллеров использую

```html
MockMultipartFile textFile1 = new MockMultipartFile(FILES_NAME, ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME_1 + "." + FILE_EXT, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, FILE_CONTENT_1.getBytes());
```

При каждом заспуске тестов в корне модуля создаются файлы. 
Как назначить им другую директорию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать вторым параметром путь, потом название файла .

Пример:

```
 targetLocation =  "src/resources/someFolder/" + FILE_ORIG_NAME;

new MockMultipartFile (FILES_NAME, **targetLocation**, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,       FILE_CONTENT_1.getBytes());
```